# NGINX configuration for static and PHP files

Tags: php, html, nginx

I am trying to configure nginx to serve static and PHP files. The config I have isn't working. I want the following local folder structure:

```
src/static/  -> contains HTML, CSS, JS, images etc
src/api/     -> contains PHP files for a small REST service
```

If I visit http://mysite.local I want to be served files from the /static folder. If I visit http://mysite.local/api I want to be served the API PHP files. I want the requests to the api to be re-written and sent to an index.php file.

Some examples:

```
http://mysite.local/test.html                   -> served from src/static/test.html
http://mysite.local/images/something.png        -> served from src/static/images/something.png
http://mysite.local/css/style.css               -> served from src/static/css/style.css

http://mysite.local/api/users                   -> served from src/api/index.php?users
http://mysite.local/api/users/bob               -> served from src/api/index.php?users/bob
http://mysite.local/api/biscuits/chocolate/10   -> served from src/api/index.php?biscuits/chocolate/10
```

The below config works for static files but not for the api files. I get a 404 error back if I visit one of the API paths.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.local;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log main;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log debug;


    location / {
        index index.html;
        root /var/www/mysite/src/static;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api {
        index index.php;
        root /var/www/mysite/src/api;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files      $uri = 404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial problem is the `root` directive in the `location /api` block, which should not include the location component as this gets appended as part of the URI, so:

```
location /api {
    root /var/www/mysite/src;
    ...
}
```

will result in a local path of `/var/www/mysite/src/api/index.php` when presented with the URI `/api/index.php`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

The `try_files` rule does not rewrite the URI as you specify in your example. If you really need the final path of the URI to be presented as a query string to `/api/index.php` you will need to use `rewrite`.

The simplest solution (if you do not need to serve static content from that location) is to replace your `try_files` with:

```
location /api {
    ...
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?$1 last;

    location ~ \.php$ { ... }
}
```

Otherwise, use a named location:

```
location /api {
    ...
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location ~ \.php$ { ... }
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?$1 last;
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. The main problem was the definition of the root in the /api location block.